# Mysql Trigger: Tried other suggestions but still get Error #1064

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I've been looking at other stackoverflow questions here but cant seem to find my fault. I think its syntax-error related. On what part did I got wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS keisan
CREATE TRIGGER keisan AFTER INSERT ON profitdb
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE shinAgentPercent;
SET @shinAgentPercent:=`AgentRisk`-`SubAgentRisk`;
SET NEW.`SubAgentProfit` = `Profit`*(`SubAgentRisk`/100);
SET NEW.`AgentProfit` = `Profit`*(@shinAgentPercent/100);
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need a closing statement indication after `drop ...` command.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS keisan $$
```

Secondly, I suggest you to go with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to set expression values for other columns of the tables.

**Example**:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS keisan $$

CREATE TRIGGER keisan BEFORE INSERT ON profitdb
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @shinAgentPercent  := NEW.AgentRisk - NEW.SubAgentRisk;

    SET NEW.SubAgentProfit := NEW.Profit * ( NEW.SubAgentRisk  / 100 );
    SET NEW.AgentProfit    := NEW.Profit * ( @shinAgentPercent / 100 );
END;

$$

-- now reset the delimiter to defaut
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, the reason I set it AFTER INSERT because the table will be filled by data from other tables first then after getting the Risk and Profit then its the time to compute the values for Agent and SubAgentProfits

Comment: For a `trigger`, data is available in hand before it is written into the table. No matter it is an `insert` or `update`. And mostly `AFTER` are used to do operations on other tables.

Comment: Oh, I see. But I didnt get what I expected. Here's what I do. I Added the trigger first. Then upon executing the Insert command to fill the table with data, I got the error #1054 - Unknown column `'AgentRisk'` in 'field list'. I deleted the trigger and the `INSERT` worked. So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: You have to tell me, what is the `AgetRisk`? If it is not a table column, then trigger can't know its value unless you calculate within its body. If `AgentRisk` and `SubAgentRisk` are table columns, then just qualify them using `NEW.` prefix.

Comment: Yes they are table columns.I still get the #1054 - Unknown column 'AgentRisk' in 'field list' upon doing INSERT. What could be the problem? I added the INSERT query on my post.

Comment: Error still props after using `NEW.AgentRisk` and `NEW.SubAgentRisk`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need an end-of-statement after your `DROP TRIGGER`?

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS keisan$$
```